# Локальные и глобальные переменные

Tags: javascript

В наличии три ссылки:

```
    <div class="menu">
    <a href="#" id="one" onclick="engine()">Rock</a>
    <a href="#" id="two" onclick="engine()">Paper</a>
    <a href="#" id="three" onclick="engine()">Scissors</a>
```

Задача, при клике на одну из ссылок менять(устанавливать) значение в глобальную переменную userChoice.

```
var userChoice; // глобальная переменная
function engineGame() { // ее вызываем при клике на ссылку
    document.getElementById('one').onclick = function() {
        userChoice = "rock";
        alert("до вызова функции userChoice = " + userChoice); // rock
    }
    document.getElementById('two').onclick = function() {
        userChoice = "paper";
        alert("до вызова функции userChoice = " + userChoice); // paper
    }
    document.getElementById('three').onclick = function() {
        userChoice = "scissors";
        alert("до вызова функции userChoice = " + userChoice); //scissors
    }
};
engineGame();
alert("после вызова функции userChoice = " + userChoice); // сразу выскакивает undefined :(
```

вопрос: 
1. Добился ли я поставленной задачи? (установить значение в глобальную переменную) или это делается как-то иначе?

Comment: Все верно, понятно что undefined  , событие то еще не выполнилось что бы переменная была переназначена .

Comment: alert внутрь onclick перенесите

Comment: т.е. после того как я кликнул на ссылку и до момента перезагрузки станицы, переменной присвоено значение в соответствии с программой? Или спрошу по другому, я правильно установил значение в глобальную переменную по клику?

Comment: Сделайте ещё одну ссылку <a href="#" id="three" onclick="alert(userChoice)">Test</a> и проверьте. Но вроде правильно.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как вернуть значение из события или из функции обратного вызова?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/554290/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0)

Answer (score 2):

Код корректен только если события назначаются после загрузки кода ссылок. Назначения событий лучше делать в теле обратчика события onload объекта window. Так-же лучше использовать функцию addEventListener на случай если это не единственное событие по ссылке:

```
var userChoice = null;
window.addEventListener("load", function() 
{
    document.getElementById("one").addEventListener("click", function() 
    {
        userChoice = "rock";
        alert(userChoice); 
    });
    document.getElementById("two").addEventListener("click", function() 
    {
        userChoice = "paper";
        alert(userChoice); 
    });
    document.getElementById("tree").addEventListener("click", function() 
    {
        userChoice = "scissors";
        alert(userChoice); 
    });
};
```

Еще лучше сделать объект GameEngine и хранить выбор пользователя в его поле не плодя глобальных переменных, тем более с таким простым именем.